# No library found for Processing?

Tags: processing, openni

I am currently working with [SimpleOpenNI](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/) and the Kinect to work on a programming project for sign language. I installed the prerequisite programs(drivers, NITE, OpenNI) on my 32-bit computer and my project compiles well on that computer.

I installed the 64-bit versions of the prereq programs on my 64-bit computer. After installing the prereq programs, I placed the SimpleOpenNI folder (I tried zipped and unzipped) in /Documents/Processing/libraries. When I try to compile, it gives me an error in Processing:

> No library found for SimpleOpenNI
>   Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the 'sketchbook' folder.

I tried many [solutions](http://code.google.com/p/simple-openni/issues/detail?id=27): I tried installing the 32 bit programs, installing programs directly from the website, and tried it on another 64-bit computer.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the SimpleOpenNI folder in /Documents/Processing/libraries/libraries, that should fix your error.